# GA (or other javascript apps) configured and called in a 12Factor-y way

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, 12factor

My app consists of 2 pieces, 1 private management and 1 payment gateway, which are deployed to different urls:

```
https://manage-my-app.com
https://pay-my-app.com
```

They need to be able to live on 1 server, however, with the domains are managed in the same `vhost` file.

I want to configure Google Analytics to run separately on each of these urls, but to store as much of the configuration in Environment Variables as possible (conforming with 12Factor).

I want to avoid using App Environments (dev, staging, production) to determine when to load GA, and I want to try to use as few variables as possible.

I'm thinking of using:

```
# manage-my-app.com vhost config
SetEnv GA_CODE something

# pay-my-app.com vhost config
SetEnv GA_CODE somethingelse
```

Then in my code, using:

```
<?php if ($ga = getenv('GA_CODE')) : ?>
// do google analytics here
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think this covers all my bases:

- The config is in the ENV
- Each deployment has its own analytics code
- Each deployment only has to maintain its own string
- Deploys with no analytics (dev, staging, etc) don't include the javascript

**BUT** I am worried it's not extensible enough.

For example:
**How should I modify my approach if I need special analytics code or config for the payment gateway to conform to our privacy policy?**

I want to avoid 2 paths, but I *cannot* rely on the url if 2 paths is the only way:

```
<?php if ($ga = getenv('GA_CODE')) : ?>
    <?php if ($url == 'pay-my-app.com') : ?>
        <!-- do it one way -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- do it some other way -->
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```